# Web service using php in linux environment

Tags: linux, windows

We would like to know is it possible for us to build a web serive based on php to run on apache web server in linux environment? The issue here is that on time to time basis we  are inserting a mysql db. Then on windows environment the same data need to be inserted as soon as possible. Will web service be the best method here or any other suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is an excellent and easy way of building a web service. You can use [JSON](http://www.json.org) or [Soap](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap/) to transport the data to and from the service.

PHP has a good addon library for SOAP called [NuSoap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/).

Note that it's a good practice to make example php clients to test your service. It's much easier to debug the service with PHP client than with an objective-c or java client.

Database. PHP is capable of writing to a remote database so if you need write to an SQL Server on a Windows machine that should be possible.

Comment: I am kind of curious because I have been writing php script for sometime. So when I say php based web service can I say I write a script which will take some get input and generate the relevant required results from the db? So then why must I use json or soap is it for formatting purposes?

Comment: No you use XML or JSON for data transport purposes. They are just data formats. If you want you could just pass arrays or csv files but most webservices use either XML or JSON. Soap is a type of webservice which uses XML exclusively. REST another popular webservice technology with uses GET, POST, DELETE and PUSH HTTP commands to manage the webservice. Often JSON or XML will be used for POST or PUSH data and the server response (even to a get or delete request).

Comment: sorry I am kind of new to this technology. In normal case I write sql query it will generate the resultset right? So what must I do extra in order for it to be a made as web service? Can I say that I need to format the resultset into xml format?

Comment: A webservice works in a client server model. The client sends the webservice a command like `get userprofile`. The service looks up the userprofile and returns it in some format (XML, JSON, Text, etc) the client then formats that data for presentation or local storage depending on the application.